# how to used less than sign in xml document?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc

I am using C#.net where I required to used xml string,which needs to populate into xmldocument. It is loading fine,but when that string has special following values in one of the node then it is not working
sometime I have html tags with style and class. so how to load that string in xml document. so How to deal with in such cases?

here my string which produces an error

```
<restdata>
 <listingAddress>
          fsdfsdf dfdf <Not Specified="">  Argentina dsfsf</listingAddress>
 <listingAddress>
 xxk dfsdf 899993 
  </listingAddress>
 </restdata>
```

in my case error may be because of `<not Specified=""`.

also sometime there may be html tags.
so how this would be used generalized way so any data my it should work fine?

Answer (score 1):

Generally if you need to use characters that are commonly reserved in XML, you can use their encoded HTML entities if you need to enter HTML data :

- Use `&lt;` for `<`
- Use `&gt;` for `>`
- Use `&amp;` for `&`
- Use `&quot;` for `"`

You can find a [complete list of them here](http://www.elizabethcastro.com/html/extras/entities.html). If you need to programatically encode HTML cotent in C#, you can use the [`HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz(v=vs.110).aspx) method :

```
// Your original text
var input = "<a href='http://example-site.com'>This is a link</a>";
// This yields &lt;a href=&#39;http://example-site.com&#39;&gt;This is a link&lt;/a&gt;
var encoded = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(input);
```